# What geometric information can be recovered from $L^2(X)$ for a manifold $X$?

Tags: manifolds, hilbert-spaces

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Statement_of_the_commutative_Gelfand-Naimark_theorem) that a compact Hausdorff topological space can be fully reconstructed from its $C^\ast$-algebra of complex valued continuous functions with the sup norm.

Are there similar (partial) results for reconstructing topological/geometrical information from the (Hilbert space structure of) $L^2(X)$ for (say) a compact manifold $X$, or more general spaces with a Borel measure? To what extent does it depend on the particular measure?

Comment: I'm fairly certain $L^2(X)$ is separable for any compact manifold. So up to an isometry it is indistinguishable from $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @JHance Thanks! I should have thought of that. It still seems counterintuitive that not even the dimension can be recovered!

Comment: I think that an abelian $C^*$ algebra with identity (probably with some  conditions on the spectrum of the elements?) can be realized as C(X), the continuous functions on a compact manifold X and X specified in some sense. A bit vague sorry but Gelfand Niamark Theorem rings a bell.

Comment: A Hilbert space, by itself, is an extremely weak invariant. At the very least you should be trying to equip it with some kind of extra structure, e.g. maybe the structure of a module over $C^{\infty}(X)$, or maybe the structure of a representation of $\text{Diff}(X)$, that sort of thing.